# ArgoCD synchronization is unable to delete services that are not configured in the repository

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, cicd, argocd

I directly applied a curl service in the environment, but the ArgoCD UI did not display this OutOfSync service and it was not deleted during synchronization.
My requirement is that other people will make changes in the environment, but regular synchronization with ArgoCD is needed to ensure consistency between the environment and the repository, without any extra configurations, even if it means clearing all services under this namespace and redeploying them.
Is there a solution for this?